# cURL to Python: Connection error when using requests module

Tags: python, curl

I want to move my bash code which uses a cURL command to a Python 2.7 script.

The cURL working command is:

```
$ curl --data "vm_id='52e4130d-ffe0-495a-87c0-fc84200252ed'&gpu_ip='10.2.0.22'&gpu_port='8308'&mock_ip='10.254.254.254'&mock_port='8308'" http://rodvr-services:8080/rodvr-assign_gpu
```

And my Python script contains this:

```
import requests
import requests.packages.urllib3
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

payload = {'vm_id': '52e4130d-ffe0-495a-87c0-fc84200252ed', 'gpu_ip': '10.2.0.22', 'gpu_port': '8308', 'mock_ip': '10.254.254.254', 'mock_port': '8308'}
r = requests.get('http://rodvr-services:8080/rodvr-assign_gpu', params=payload)
```

When I execute the script, I get the following error:

```
$ python exec.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "exec.py", line 9, in <module>
  r = requests.post('http://rodvr-services:8080/rodvr-assign_gpu', params=payload)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 112, in post 
  return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
  return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 502, in request
  resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 612, in send
  r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
  raise ConnectionError(err, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\n',))
```

Just in case, I checked what would happen using Python 3, and this is the output:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='rodvr-services', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /rodvr-assign_gpu?mock_ip=10.254.254.254&vm_id=52e4130d-ffe0-495a-87c0-fc84200252ed&gpu_ip=10.2.0.22&mock_port=8308&gpu_port=8308 (Caused by <class 'http.client.BadStatusLine'>:
```

However, using the *urllib2* library, it works:

```
data = "vm_id='52e4130d-ffe0-495a-87c0-fc84200252ed'&gpu_ip='10.2.0.22'&gpu_port='8308'&mock_ip='10.254.254.254'&mock_port='8308'"
r = urllib2.Request(url='http://rodvr-services:8080/rodvr-assign_gpu', data=data)
f = urllib2.urlopen(r)
print f.read()
```

Comment: All your query arguments seem to have quotation marks. Try to add them like `"'value'"`.

Comment: @KlausD. Using `payload = {'vm_id': "'52e4130d-ffe0-495a-87c0-fc84200252ed'", 'gpu_ip': "'10.2.0.22'", 'gpu_port': "'8308'", 'mock_ip': "'10.254.254.254'", 'mock_port': "'8308'"}` produces the same output.

Comment: Can you check the servers log?

Comment: @KlausD. yes! Which one could be more useful?

Answer (score 0):

Try `r = requests.post('http://rodvr-services:8080/rodvr-assign_gpu', data=payload)`

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://curl.trillworks.com/) website helps you to convert your curl command to python code.
You can see the code suggested by that website below:

```
import requests

data = [
  ('vm_id', '\'52e4130d-ffe0-495a-87c0-fc84200252ed\''),
  ('gpu_ip', '\'10.2.0.22\''),
  ('gpu_port', '\'8308\''),
  ('mock_ip', '\'10.254.254.254\''),
  ('mock_port', '\'8308\''),
]

requests.post('http://rodvr-services:8080/rodvr-assign_gpu', data=data)
# it is slightly different from your code
```

Due to my personal problems with my laptop, I can't test your code. hope this works for you.

Comment: I tested this solution and I still have the same error.